# MongoDB: How to get Object value of lookup collection

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, object

I'm new on MongoDB. I want to find object value to lookup collection.

Here are the collections:

Langauge:

```
{
  _id: 15,
  language:English,
  status: Active
},
{
  _id: 20,
  language:Spanish,
  status: Active
},
```

Category:

Here `15, 20` is language ID in `name` Object

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: { 
          15: Office,
          20: Oficina 
        },
  status: Active
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: { 
          15: Restaurant,
          20: Restaurante 
        },
  status: Active
 },
```

Property:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: { 
          15: Lake View,
          20: Vista al lago 
        },
  cat_id : 1
  status: Active
},
{
  _id: 2,
  name: { 
          15: The Apple,
          20: La manzana 
        },
  cat_id : 1
  status: Active
 },
{
  _id: 3,
  name: { 
          15: Blue Monday,
          20: Lunes azul 
        },
  cat_id : 2
  status: Active
 },
```

Query:

```
var langId = 15;
db.Property.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:
      {
        from: 'Category',
        localField: 'cat_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'catdetails',
      },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: `$name.${langId}`,
      cat_id: 1,
      status: 1,
      'catdetails._id': 1,
      'catdetails.name': `$catdetails.name.${langId}`,
      'catdetails.status': 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Lake View",
    "cat_id": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "catdetails": {
                    "_id": "1",
                    "name":[ "Office" ],
                  }
   },
   {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "The Apple",
    "cat_id": 2,
    "status": "Active",
    "catdetails": {
                    "_id": "1",
                    "name":[ "Office" ],
                  }
   },
   {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Blue Monday",
    "cat_id": 2,
    "status": "Active",
    "catdetails": {
                    "_id": 2,
                    "name":[ "Restaurant" ],
                  }
   },
]
```

In Result in catdetails Object `name` comes in array symbol like this `"name":[ "Restaurant" ]` I want this without array symbol like this `"name":"Restaurant"`

Expected Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Lake View",
    "cat_id": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "catdetails": {
                    "_id": "1",
                    "name":"Office",
                  }
   },
   {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "The Apple",
    "cat_id": 2,
    "status": "Active",
    "catdetails": {
                    "_id": "1",
                    "name":"Office",
                  }
   },
   {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "Blue Monday",
    "cat_id": 2,
    "status": "Active",
    "catdetails": {
                    "_id": 2,
                    "name":"Restaurant",
                  }
   },
]
```

How can I change in my query to this type of result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
var langId = 15;
db.Property.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: 'category',
            localField: 'cat_id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'catdetails',
        },
    }, { $addFields: { name: `$name.${langId}`, catdetails: { $arrayElemAt: ["$catdetails", 0] } } },
    { $addFields: { 'catdetails.name': `$catdetails.name.${langId}` } }])
```

Couple of changes includes removal of `_id :1`, as it will be retained by default in `$project` that need not to be included, Also if you've more fields to retain then you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) rather than clumsy `$project`.

**Ref :** [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html), [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html)